# chrome debugging not working as expected

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, react-native

I'm building an app using RN and have trouble with chrome debugging: In some cases, the debugger stops at places where I have not placed any breakpoint (even when Pause on caught exceptions is disabled) and other times chrome will not let me place breakpoint on the place where I want to do so and instead will place it on a method header somewhere down the file.

This makes the debugging experience :/.

Has anyone a fix for this? Thanks.

my .babelrc:

```
{
  "presets": [
  "react-native","react-native-stage-0/decorator-support"
  ]
}
```

Comment: the problem disappeared after a RN upgrade